# short date in bash PS1 prompt

Tags: bash, ps1

You can use \d in the your PS1 confuration to display a long date ie. Tues 18 May, but how can I get it to display it in a format like 18.05.2012 for example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
PS1="\$(date +%d.%m.%Y) > "
export PS1
```

Comment: Better to use the shell substitution as per FatalError answer below.

Answer (score 77):

Try including `\D{%d.%m.%Y}`. You can use any time format supported by `strftime(3)`.

Comment: This should be accepted as it uses shell substitution instead of an external command in a subshell.

Answer (score 23):

Rather than telling the shell to execute the date command each time, you can use the built-in format:

```
\D{%F %T}
```

to give you date and time in this in format: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 21):

Use `\D{format}` where `format` is a `strftime` format code.
For example:

```
$ export PS1='\D{%d.%m.%Y}$ '
08.02.2012$
```

Comment: Great answer for my problem. However how do you make this permament?

Comment: Depending on your platform, you could put these kind of customizations in ~/.bash_profile which is read when a new interactive shell is started.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this that display time:

```
$ PS1="\n\t \u@\h:\w# "

08:18:57 user@localhost:/home/user#
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to apply this to PS1 specifically (maybe someone can edit this question to replace this part with the best working bit from other questions).

BUT you can get short date formatted according to your current locale with:

```
date +%x
```