# How to add time on git command prompt

Tags: git, command-prompt

I want to add current time on git command prompt. with keeping the same actual parameters.

> How to do it like the following image.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [short date in bash PS1 prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200862/short-date-in-bash-ps1-prompt)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a complete answer to your question. Please let me know if there is anything more you would like to know that related to this particular question.

Comment: @joe i want to add date on prompt command

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigate to your Git installation folder to where your profiles are located: `Git\etc\profile.d` and open the file called `git-prompt.sh`. Change the last block of code to include the time stamp like this:

```
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
PS1="$PS1"' \A \D{%d/%m/%Y}'   # time & date
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
```

Just to highlight, this is the line you are inserting just before bash inserts a new line:

```
PS1="$PS1"' \A \D{%d/%m/%Y}'   # time & date
```

`\A` will display the current time in 24-hour `HH:MM` format and `\D{format}` will display the date with a custom format. The format takes any arguments supported by [strftime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). The format we have used is broken down into these segments:

```
%m - The month as a decimal number (range 01 to 12). 
%d - The day of the month as a decimal number (range 01 to 31). 
%y - The year as a decimal number without a century (range 00 to 99).
```

That should give you a following console output similar to this:

```
~/Desktop/Code/carhabti (master) 01:28 23/06/2019
```

Here is a [list](https://bneijt.nl/blog/post/add-a-timestamp-to-your-bash-prompt/) of escape sequences that are used to format time in bash:

```
\t     the current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
\T     the current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
\@     the current time in 12-hour am/pm format
\A     the current time in 24-hour HH:MM format
```

Comment: thx for repling, just i'm not finding the path of git on windows 10, if you can help me

Comment: The installation folder should have the same structure independent of operating system you're using. You're looking for the following file inside the directory **where you installed Git**: `\etc\profile.d`

Comment: yes, just i forget and cant find where is my installed Git :D

Comment: One way would be to open your git bash console, then open your `windows task manager` and navigate to `Processes` tab. Right-click the `git-bash.exe` process from the list of image names and select `Open file location`.

Comment: A perhaps simpler way would be to find it in the [list of installed programs](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-do-i-find-my-installed-programs-windows-10/18432440-af63-43a9-b3bf-62ef6de2e8e8).